# Showing image(coming from database) dynamically in crystal report using ImagePath C#

Tags: image, crystal-reports

I store image path in database like this: `UploadedImage/FabricImage/11115.JPG`.

I want to show them dynamically in a crystal report. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional formula to dynamically change the location of a report’s image.

1. Add an image to the report: `-> Insert -> Picture`
   This image will act as a placeholder.
   Ensure that the placeholder is the same size as the one that will be dynamically loaded, otherwise the image will be scaled.
2. Change the image’s Graphic Location:

   - right click image
   - select Format Graphic…
   - select Picture tab
   - click the conditional-formula button (looks like x+2)
   - set the formula’s text to the name of the formula or parameter field that will contain the image’s URL
   - save the formula and click the OK button
   - Save the report

Source: [cogniza.com](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/)

Comment: Tried that. But it didn't work. It showed the default image. By the way, I solved the problem by converting image to base 64. That worked for me. Thanks for your reply.