# Dynamic images in VB.NET 2005 Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using **VB.NET 2005**. I need to **insert images to crystal report** i have stored the path of images in my **data base**. there is no graphic location option in my version of Crystal report.  how is it possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing image(coming from database) dynamically in crystal report using ImagePath C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418339/showing-imagecoming-from-database-dynamically-in-crystal-report-using-imagepat)

Comment: @MatSnow I don't have the option graphic location in my version of crystal report

Comment: Oh OK, my fault. I assumed that this is available in all versions.

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is a datatable, add a new column of Byte() type like so:

```
Dim image As New DataColumn
With image
    .ColumnName = "photo"
    .DataType = GetType(Byte())
    .AllowDBNull = True
End With
yourTable.Columns.Add(image)
```

Now set the value of your image based on the path stored in your data source. (You should include the column that stores the path of your image when you retrieve your data.)

```
For Each row As DataRow in yourTable.Rows
   row("photo") = GetImageData(row("path_to_photo"))
Next
yourTable.AcceptChanges()



Private Function GetImageData(ByVal cFileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = _
            New System.IO.FileStream(cFileName, _
            System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
    Dim br As System.IO.BinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(fs)
    Return (br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(br.BaseStream.Length)))
End Function
```

Then set yourTable as the datasource of your report

```
yourReport.SetDataSource(yourTable)
```

Of course, your crystal report definition's data source must match the data source that you pass to it. Drag the "photo" column to your report and photos should be displayed.

Comment: is there any way without storing the image in the db.

Comment: It's not a db. Just a data table. I don't see any other way of doing it